# Accessing null pointer causes seg fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a template based class as such:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo();
        bool iterateFoos();
    private:
        Foo<T> *babyFoos[5];
};
```

In the constructor, I set all the babyFoos = NULL:

```
template <typename T>
Foo<T>::Foo()
{
    for(int i =0; i<5; i++) babyFoos[i] = NULL;
}
```

This if condition throws a seg fault however:

```
template <typename T>
bool Foo<T>::iterateFoos()
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(babyFoos[i] != NULL) { do stuff }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why?

Comment: Please post a small program exhibiting the behaviour.

Comment: Please post `iterateFoos()`

Comment: Either `i` is out of range of `babyFoo` (or `this`) doesn't contain a sensible value. Post complete code.

Comment: @MikeCorcoran I believe that is not the problem since babyFoos is a definite length array of pointers

Comment: Updated my post. The range is not the issue, afai can tell.

Comment: @texasbruce you're right, i haven't messed with fixed length arrays in a while...

Comment: Well, if the question info is accurate, `this` must have invalid value... Or there is some memory corruption in which case basically anything can happen.

Comment: The class is fine. Maybe `Foo` itself is not properly instantiated.

Comment: You code as-posted does *nothing*. Nowhere do i see an actual *instance* of a `Foo<T>` being created nor used. Post *real* code that exhibits the *real* problem. What you have here and a `main()` that actually uses it will be sufficient. as-written it could be an invalid instance (in which case `this` is invalid) or a copy-issue involving a destructor you're conveniently not showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really the `if` condition itself causing the segfault, that means the value of `this` inside `iterateFoos()` is invalid - perhaps you're dereferencing a null/dangling pointer when calling it.

Comment: A silly mistake. 'this' is the problem here. Thanks.